# Listview/DataGrid returning back {collection}

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

In one of my columns I have a List that I would like to show in a ListView or datagrid.

The class looks like:

```
class Cab
{
    public Cab()
    {
        Stations = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Medication { get; set; }
    public List<string> Stations { get; set; }
}
```

And here is what the outcome looks like:

[image]

I have tried several different ways but I don't know what search term to look for. What I would like to do is to format the stations into something that looks like : ER,ICU,Foo,Bar next to each med.

```
<ListView x:Name="myCab">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Medication" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Medication}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Stations" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Stations}">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column 3" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [ValueConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38773/WPF-Introduction-Databinding-Styles-IValueConverte)

Basically The first step is to create class `ListToStringConverter` which implements `IValueConverter`:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Collections; 

namespace myNameSpace
{
   public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
      {
         string returnValue = string.Empty; 
         List<string> targetList = value as List<string>; 

         foreach(string s in targetList)
         {
           if(!returnValue == string.Empty)
              returnValue += ", " + s; 
           else 
              returnValue += s; 
         }

         return returnValue; 
      }     

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
          List<string> returnValue = new List<string>(); 

          string input = value as string; 
          returnValue.AddRange(input.Split(",")); 

          return returnValue; 
       }
   }
}
```

then use the ValueConverter in your XAML by

- Importing Namespacee
- Declaring in your window resources your value converter
- modifying your binding to use the value converter

// assumming you imported the namespace

```
<Window>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ListToStringConverter x:Key="listFormatter" /> 

</Window.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="myCab">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Medication" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Medication}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Stations" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Stations Converter={StaticResource listFormatter}}">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column 3" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
</Window>
```

The beauty of this is that you get the result you want without polluting your class with UI Specific Properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your class to be something like

```
class Cab
{
    public Cab()
    {
        Stations = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Medication { get; set; }
    public List<string> Stations { get; set; }

    public string StationsToString
    {
        set {}
        get { return string.Join(",", this.Stations.ToArray()); }
    }
}
```

Then you set `StationsToString` as the property to bind the list.

Hope this helps.

Regards